# Swift and Cocoa - Where to find the Class Reference Documentation?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I'm learning Swift and how to make Apps through Xcode.

I'm creating an App and want to learn this from the Apple documentation.

From this code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: NSTextField!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    }

    @IBAction func clickBtn(sender: NSButton) {

        myLabel.stringValue = "Testing"

    }

}
```

I want to know the meaning of `NSTextField` and therefore I looked at: [Apple NSTextField Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/NSTextField)

But I'm not able to find the `stringValue` method in this document.

Where would be the documentation for each part of the OSX/iOS code?

Comment: @vihan1086 nope... That's for Swift and its syntax, no documentation on the methods and different functions for each object.

Comment: Also consider [Dash](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-api-docs/id935284832?ls=1&mt=8) as the document viewer, it has a great search feature for those occasions you are looking for a method to fit a need. Dash accesses the Apple documentation it is just a different presentation tool. It also supports 3rd party SDKs and other languages.

Comment: In addition to CRD's answer, you can Option-double-click on a symbol, in this case the `stringValue` property name, to be taken to the documentation for it. Even though there are multiple classes which have a `stringValue` property, Xcode has enough awareness of the context to take you to the relevant one on `NSControl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page you reference at the top you will see the inheritance chain of `NSTextField`. You didn't find `stringValue` as it comes from `NSControl` - click on that class in the inheritance chain.

The documentation is where you found it on the web, and provided with Xcode.

HTH